# What type of UV-resistant (fade-resistant) paint is best for a rain barrel made of polyethylene? It will be in a greenhouse

Tags: painting, paint

What type of UV-resistant (fade-resistant) paint is best as the outer coating of a rain barrel? The barrel is made of polyethylene. It will sit in a greenhouse, so other than direct sunlight and slight temperature variations, it's relatively protected from other types of abuse.

I would like to use black paint to maximize solar-heat absorption.

Basically the paint needs to be durable, adhere well and won't crack or come off over time.

Comment: Wrap it in black plastic.

Answer (score 2):

“Adhere to polyethylene” is going to be your problem. It Does Not Like things sticking to it.

I suppose you could voraciously scuff-sand to create a surface with a lot of “tooth”, then paint it in epoxy, hoping for a mechanical bind.  Ideally epoxy primer like Amercote, but that is too dangerous for consumers to use. I suppose something like West System 105 would do.  Sunlight will quickly destroy the epoxy, so you’ll need to topcoat it with something.  But paints stick a great deal better to epoxy then to polyethylene.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess you're only suggesting the undercoat?

Comment: “Only”??? Prep and primer are the key to it. Get that right and topcoat barely matters.

Comment: I feel like this is an incomplete answer. What topcoat would fit the bill?

Comment: @jinren depends. Are we talking direct application onto run of the mill poly, or has the surface been prepared?

Comment: Assuming we used the epoxy undercoat like you suggested. What topcoat?

Comment: @Jinren Well I say once you have a good primer, the choice is not critical.  My usual “go-to” for a good compromise between durability and price is Rustoleum true alkyd topcoat, so like a 242251 Flat Black.